# Whats wrong with the following date sort query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I am using the following query to sort the output. It works in some cases but not all. Output picture given. Any suggestion why? any alternate please.

```
Select 
    'playing' As activity,
    max(ad.xDate) As xDate,
    Isnull(sum(t.TimePerDay), 0) As TimePerDay 
From    
    AllDates As ad With (Nolock) 
Left Join 
    @test As t On ad.xDate = t.date
Group By
    datepart(wk, ad.xDate)
Order By
    YEAR(datepart(wk, ad.xDate)) DESC, MONTH(datepart(wk, ad.xDate)) DESC, DAY(datepart(wk, ad.xDate))
```

[image]

Comment: `YEAR(datepart(...))` doesn't make any sense, `datepart` returns an `INT`, you can't extract a `YEAR` or a `MONTH`

Comment: any alternate solution

Comment: not without understanding what you want as a result

Comment: I wanted to sort it. Gordon is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you extracting the week before getting the year and month?

I think you want:

```
ORDER BY MIN(ad.xDate) DESC
```

This will order by an arbitrary date on each row.